# If $\sum_{i=1}^vu_i\otimes v_i =0$ then $v_i=0$ for all $i=1,\cdots, n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$, $V$ be $K$-vector spaces. Let $u_1,\cdots, u_n\in U$ be linear independent vectors and $v_1,\cdots, v_n\in V$ arbitrary vectors. Show that if $\sum_{i=1}^vu_i\otimes v_i =0$ then $v_i=0$ for all $i=1,\cdots, n$

I can obviously show the converse, but it does not suffice. I tried to find the answer here but I couldn't. It seems simple but I don't know how to begin

Comment: Should it be $\sum_{i=1}^n$ rather than $\sum_{i=1}^v$ in the title and text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w_1, \ldots, w_m$ be a basis of $V$. Then $u_i \otimes w_j$ is linearly independent in 
$U \otimes V$. One can write

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i \otimes v_i = \sum_{i=1}^{n} u_i \otimes \left( \sum_{j=1}^{m}c^i_j w_j\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} c^i_j (u_i \otimes w_j) = 0.$$

Clearly, this implies that all $c^i_j = 0$. Thus, $v_i = \sum c^i_j w_j = 0$.